# is there a way to use icons in ListTile title or subtitle?

Tags: flutter

```
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(widget.challenge.name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17)),
            subtitle: Text(
              'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
            trailing:Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight),
            isThreeLine: true,
          ),
```

I've coded above and I want to add icons to the subtitle or the title, not just in trailing or leading. Is there a way to do this? I usually use Wrap() to mix Text and Icon - can I use it here?

Thanks !

Comment: title expects a widget, so you can

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be anything as long as it's a widget.

```
child: ListTile(
  title: Icon(
    Icons.music_note,
    color:Colors.white
    ),
    ...
```